# Wpf 4.0: Drawing Aliased FormattedText/GlyphRun?

Tags: c#, wpf, text, drawing

In Wpf 4.0 you can turn off Text antialiasing for a Frameworkelement and all its children by putting this e.g. in the main window:

```
TextOptions.SetTextFormattingMode(this, TextFormattingMode.Display);
TextOptions.SetTextRenderingMode(this, TextRenderingMode.Aliased);
```

This works fine for TextBlocks etc. but it does not seem to have any effect when using the DrawingContext's methods DrawText(FormattedText)  or DrawGlyphRun(..).

**Is there any chance of drawing aliased Text via DrawingContext** ? (I know about the FormattedText.BuildGeometry() trick , but this looks awful when using small text sizes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have WPF4 right now, so I cant test it. But quick scan through MSDN shows you can use [DrawingVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual.aspx). Set your RenderingMode here and then use `RenderOpen` to get DrawingContext.

Question is where and how you want to draw this text.

Comment: Yes, you can set TextOptions.SetTextFormattingMode to a DrawingVisual. When using FormattedText, you can get very crisp results! Unfortunately it seems that this way you can't get a GlyphRunDrawing to be drawn aliased. I would prefer Glyphrun because it's much faster than FormattedText and I've got a lot of elements to draw in an overridden OnRender() method of a Frameworkelement.

Answer (score 2):

How to remove glyphrun blur effect:

```
var glyphRun = new GlyphRun(typeface, 0, false, emSize, glyphIndices, p, advanceWidths, null, null, null, null, null, null);
var rect = glyphRun.ComputeAlignmentBox();
Double halfPenWidth = 0.5;

GuidelineSet guidelines = new GuidelineSet();
guidelines.GuidelinesX.Add(rect.Left + halfPenWidth);
guidelines.GuidelinesX.Add(rect.Right + halfPenWidth);
guidelines.GuidelinesY.Add(rect.Top + halfPenWidth);
guidelines.GuidelinesY.Add(rect.Bottom + halfPenWidth);
drawingContext.PushGuidelineSet(guidelines);
drawingContext.DrawGlyphRun(brush, glyphRun);
drawingContext.Pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an overloaded constructor for `FormattedText` that allows specifying a `TextFormattingMode`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee474866.aspx

Comment: `TextFormattingMode` does not help drawing aliased text.